# I want to change the key of an multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'ref_id' => string '11' (length=2)
      'ref_own' => string 'kevin' (length=5)
      'ref_nom' => string 'Herbert' (length=7)
      'ref_ape' => string 'Guzman' (length=6)
      'ref_tel1' => string '12345678' (length=8)
      'ref_tel2' => string '87654321' (length=8)
      'ref_tel3' => string '' (length=0)
      'ref_who' => string 'Daniel Quevedo' (length=14)
      'ref_fecha' => string '2014-12-03 10:16:10' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'ref_id' => string '12' (length=2)
      'ref_own' => string 'kevin' (length=5)
      'ref_nom' => string 'Afid' (length=4)
      'ref_ape' => string 'Rivas' (length=5)
      'ref_tel1' => string '12345678' (length=8)
      'ref_tel2' => string '32132121' (length=8)
      'ref_tel3' => string '' (length=0)
      'ref_who' => string 'Rick Delgadillo' (length=15)
      'ref_fecha' => string '2014-12-03 10:16:10' (length=19)
```

I want to changue this keys:

ref_id
ref_own
ref_nom
ref_ape
ref_tel1
ref_tel2
ref_tel3
ref_who

I try with array_push but nothing happend...
ideas?

Comment: Why would you try with `array_push`?  What do you want to change them to?

Comment: I'm trying to change the column names of a csv report... My default code, the column name are that array key... So, I just want to get the same array with other name for that keys, then the report will return the column names that I want.

Comment: Change how you assign them when you read the csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it like this

```
  <?php
  // your data
  $array =  array(array(
        'ref_id' =>  '11',
        'ref_own' =>  'kevin',
        'ref_nom' =>  'Herbert',
        'ref_ape' =>  'Guzman',
        'ref_tel1' =>  '12345678' ,
        'ref_tel2' =>  '87654321',
        'ref_tel3' =>  '',
        'ref_who' =>  'Daniel Quevedo',
        'ref_fecha' =>  '2014-12-03 10:16:10'),
        array(
        'ref_id' =>  '12',
        'ref_own' =>  'something',
        'ref_nom' =>  'data',
        'ref_ape' =>  'Guzman',
        'ref_tel1' =>  '12345678' ,
        'ref_tel2' =>  '87654321',
        'ref_tel3' =>  '',
        'ref_who' =>  'Daniel Quevedo',
        'ref_fecha' =>  '2014-12-03 10:16:10'));

  // new keys
  $newKeys = ['ref_id' => 'Reference ID',
              'ref_own'=> 'Reference Owner',
              'ref_nom' => 'Reference Number',
              'ref_ape' => 'Reference APE',
              'ref_tel1' => 'Reference Tel1',
              'ref_tel2' => 'Reference Tel2',
              'ref_tel3' => 'Reference Tel3',
              'ref_who' => 'Reference who',
              'ref_fecha' => 'Reference fecha'];

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
      $array[$key][$newKeys[$k]] = $v;
      unset($array[$key][$k]);
     }
  }
  var_dump($array);
```

output

```
  array (size=2)
    0 => 
      array (size=9)
        'Reference ID' => string '11' (length=2)
        'Reference Owner' => string 'kevin' (length=5)
        'Reference Number' => string 'Herbert' (length=7)
        'Reference APE' => string 'Guzman' (length=6)
        'Reference Tel1' => string '12345678' (length=8)
        'Reference Tel2' => string '87654321' (length=8)
        'Reference Tel3' => string '' (length=0)
        'Reference who' => string 'Daniel Quevedo' (length=14)
        'Reference fecha' => string '2014-12-03 10:16:10' (length=19)
    1 => 
      array (size=9)
        'Reference ID' => string '12' (length=2)
        'Reference Owner' => string 'something' (length=9)
        'Reference Number' => string 'data' (length=4)
        'Reference APE' => string 'Guzman' (length=6)
        'Reference Tel1' => string '12345678' (length=8)
        'Reference Tel2' => string '87654321' (length=8)
        'Reference Tel3' => string '' (length=0)
        'Reference who' => string 'Daniel Quevedo' (length=14)
        'Reference fecha' => string '2014-12-03 10:16:10' (length=19)
```